# Debian stuck at the login screen

Tags: debian, logs, password

I don't know what is the problem, cause everything was ok with my laptop and debian, i have the last image with kde plasma desktop and i rebooted my pc and now I'm stuck at the login screen. I can enter my password but it is like "enter" does not work but it is not the case, i have 2 "enter" on my keyboard and both don't work to apply the password.
During this problem, maybe I could choose "recovery mode" and from that, maybe we could open desktop environment from there?
Idea?
Thanks

Comment: "logging screen"? do you mean "login screen".  If so, I would recommend switching VCs, (try Control-Alt-F1) and doing a command line login.

Comment: Yes sorry, login screen. I did ctrl alt f1 but even if I was logged onto tty mode, i can't access to web environment desktop

Comment: You can't access a gui web server, but you can access almost everything needed.  More importantly, this test (assuming it worked) proves that the problem lies in the display manager instead of the login itself.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a solution? It seems that from tty my wifi does not work

Comment: It looks like you did login on the console.  I'm afraid I don't know the details of the KDE environment...  ...including how it turns on networking...  My only thought is to use apt-get or aptitude to "reinstall" the installed KDE packages.  Maybe one or more of them are corrupted.

Comment: A thought... create a new user (`sudo adduser newusername`) and try logging in on that user.  If that works, then the problem is in your original user's configurations.

Comment: Ok to create that, just to do that in tty mode?

Comment: right, choosing what you want for the username.

Comment: Finaly I created a new user, but same thing, does not work

Comment: Login on the console in TTY mode, and run `df -h`. Is any of your disks 100% in use? Starting a GUI session requires writing a small file or two, and if your disk is too full to allow that, the session will fail as soon as it begins. Also check the log files: your home directory will have a hidden file named `.xsession-errors`, and in `/var/log/` directory there should be a log file for your display manager (`gdm`, `sddm` or something-else-`dm`). Those might contain error messages describing what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks @telcoM, I will do that, Im a newbee so not easy, but what I know is my HDD is basicaly empty, I have 250GB and maybe 35GB is using. Also about the log and ...xsession-errors'' what I have to enter in TTY mode to access ?  thanks

Comment: Finaly I reinstalled debian with kde, setup again all my things and i rebooted my laptop after an app installation and bang same thing happens.

Comment: Using a default shell, `less $HOME/.xsession-errors` should display the per-user GUI session log file if it exists. Also check `journalctl _UID=$(id -u)`. In both cases, scroll with arrow keys; type `q` to exit the viewer. Looks like `/var/log/*dm.log` is no longer used: try `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sddm.service` instead.

Comment: about : 'less $HOME/.xsession-errors­''    it says : '' no such files or folders